# How to add voice output in android?

Tags: android

I m making a quiz type app.
I want that when the user types the correct or incorrect answer, the user should be informed through spoken voice in addition to display.

how can we implement this thing in android?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the TextToSpeech functionnality provided by android (Added in API level 4)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

```
TextToSpeech ttobj=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
   @Override
   public void onInit(int status) {
   }
}
);

ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
```

and finally

```
ttobj.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: **4.+** is confusing. It seems you mean **Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)** and later. In reality, TTS has been introduced with API Level 4 (Android 1.6).

Answer (score 1):

So you want a tutorial on TTS (Text To Speech).
Here's [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655709/Using-Text-to-Speech-TTS-engine-in-an-Android-appl).